# Ajax for getting list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajax

It shows `undefined` in the `alert()`..

```
    $.ajax({
      // url: "https://sharepoint.com/sites/FE/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items",
      url: "https://sharepoint.com/sites/FE/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/getitembyid('"+$id+"')",
        type: "GET",     
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {

            alert("success");
alert(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
         alert("error");
         alert($id);

        }
    });
```

With second `url`, it shows the alert success but it is not fetching items by `id`.

Comment: Stop using ``alert()`` You will save heaps of time after learning all about F12 -Developer Tools: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: did any answer help you? @vikash

Answer (score 2):

Use `alert(data.d)` instead of `alert(data.d.results)`.

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/getitembyid('"+$id+"')
```

Above endpoint means, you are requesting for a single item. For multiple items, endpoint will be

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Features')/Items
```

And items will be in `data.results`.

**Difference:**

`data.results` is for multiple items

`data.d` is for single item

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Features')/GetItemById(2)",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: It takes `GetItemById('9')` or `GetItemById(9)` but does not take `GetItemById("9")`. In OP's question output will be something like `GetItemById('9')`.

Comment: Yes ID needed to be passed as Int ad also data.d should be used instead of data.d.results
Two errors needed to be rectified in above code to make it work.

Comment: I can see that there is only one error. Please see my previous comment. @AnkitkumarMalde